# Vivaldi PPA: NO_PUBKEY errors

Tags: 22.04, lts, gnupg, vivaldi

Vivaldi appears to have an issue with managing public keys. Apparently this is due to old keys being present in the local system. Errors displayed similar to:

```
W: Während der Überprüfung der Signatur trat ein Fehler auf. Das Depot wurde nicht aktualisiert und die vorherigen Indexdateien werden verwendet. GPG-Fehler: https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb stable Release: Die folgenden Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden, weil ihr öffentlicher Schlüssel nicht verfügbar ist: NO_PUBKEY 124F149833EAAB8E
```

when attempting to update packages with `apt-get`.

```
System:
      Kernel: 5.15.0-94-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.9
        Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
```

Answer (score -1):

Despite several discussions here and elsewhere pointing at `apt-get`, `apt` / apt key management (deprecated) or `dpkg` related commands, the issue is related to GPG key management. Vivaldi help pages  are also not helpful to this regard.

Here is how I solved the issue:

1. Navigate to the Vivaldi download page and download the latest .deb package
2. Open a terminal and remove/purge Vivaldi from system `sudo apt-get purge vivaldi* && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. In case `apt-get update` doesn't come up with the error again continue with
4. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` in nemo with elevated rights (system admin)
5. Delete all entries in the directory with names starting with "vivaldi"
6. Install the latest Vivaldi .deb package via any package installation (I personally prefer GDebi)
7. run `apt-get update` again to check - the error message should be gone